# Adobe Reader does not open file created with [xetex]{\attachfile2}

Tags: xetex, lyx, pdf, attachfile

I have been using `\attachfile2` successfully to create PDF documents with LaTeX already. However, when switching to XeTeX, I find the Adobe Reader says it cannot  open the file due to security settings.

On clicking the attachment settings, I note the embedded files have no names and no size information.

[image]

I am using LyX to create the PDFXeTeX file.

```
%% LyX 2.1.0beta1 created this file.  
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,oneside,english,smallheadings]{scrbook}  
\usepackage{fontspec}  
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text,Numbers=OldStyle]{Verdana}  
\setsansfont[Mapping=tex-text]{FreeSans}  
\setmonofont{cmr10}  
\usepackage{fancyhdr}  
\pagestyle{fancy}  
\setcounter{tocdepth}{0}  
\usepackage{color}  
\usepackage{float}  
\usepackage{setspace}  
\setstretch{1.3}  
\usepackage[unicode=true,pdfusetitle,  
 bookmarks=false,  
 breaklinks=true,pdfborder={0 0 0},backref=section,colorlinks=true]  
 {hyperref}  

\makeatletter  

% LyX specific LaTeX commands.  
\pdfpageheight\paperheight  
\pdfpagewidth\paperwidth  


\@ifundefined{date}{}{\date{}}  
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.  
\usepackage[xetex]{attachfile2}  

\AtBeginDocument{  
  \def\labelitemiii{\(\triangleright\)}  
}  

\makeatother  

\usepackage{xunicode}  
\usepackage{polyglossia}  
\setdefaultlanguage{english}  
\begin{document}  

\title{testing attached files}  

\maketitle  

\section{Test}  

Link see \textattachfile{2_1.png}{this citation}    
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

probably you are no longer looking for the answer :^)
Had the same error and did not find a solution in the world wide web.

It helped to remove the options from hyperref.

```
\usepackage{hyperref}
```

Just wanted to post this here in case anyone else stumbles across.